# metal reinforcements on wood

Tags: phrase-request

What is the name for metal elements reinforcing and protecting wooden elements, for example on coffers, doors, wooden window shutters, even covers of finest ancient books - often decorative?

(my attempts at Google Translate returns only pipe plumbing parts apparently).

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a chest i would call them *metal fittings*, maybe also *metal embellishments* if they are purely decorative, but for a door there is also [*door furniture*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/door-furniture).

Answer (score 3):

I would call these simply *ironwork*.  From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ironwork):

> Ironwork is any weapon, artwork, utensil or architectural feature made of iron especially used for decoration.

As you can see, the term *is* somewhat more general than what you describe, but it seems to be to be appropriate.  One of the images Wikipedia gives seems to fit your description, as well:

[image: Image licensed under Creative Commons CC0 1.0 Universal Public Domain Dedication]

I'm not certain that this is the best term, but it's the best one I can think of.

Answer (score -1):

We can call these as Metal carvings on wood.

Comment: Whosoever Downvoted : Please provide a valid reason

Comment: Not the downvoter, but metal is not carved; so the terminology is simply incorrect.

Comment: If metal is not carved , then what will you call these images which I found under the search word metal carvings : https://www.google.co.in/search?q=metal+carvings&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=8_8xUsLFHcSQrQfZ9oHYCQ&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAQ&biw=1366&bih=667&dpr=1

Comment: worked, etched, welded, shaped, tooled.

Comment: So you mean the search results shown by google are wrong?!!

Comment: Google has a vested interest in presenting you with what you meant, as opposed to what you said.  You may notice that if you spell a word wrong, their default is to say "we fixed that for you, click here if you really meant (wrong-spelling)."  So if you give them a term that is technically incorrect but understandable, they'll give you results based on their understanding.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10582/discussion-between-sweet72-and-hellion)